# ¿Cómo alinear verticalmente un texto a la derecha de una imagen?

Tags: html, css

Cree una cabezera en la cual quiero insertar un logo a la izquierda seguido de un titulo que quede centrado y a la mitad del logo, como por ejemplo esto:
con el codigo que tengo hasta el momento no lo eh logrado, alguien podria ayudarme porfavor.

[image: ejemplo]

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   } 
   #cabecera {
     
    background: #FFFBB9;
    border: 2px solid #0a3fee;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .logo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
     border: 2px solid #ee930a;
     margin: none;
     
   }
```

```html
<html>
            
<head>
<title>Mi pagina</title>
             
</head>
            
<div id="agrupar">
<header id="cabecera">
<img class="logo" src="LOGO.png">
<h1 id="titulo"> titulo de mi pagina</h1>
</header>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Puedes utilizar `flexBox`

1. En el bloque padre `cabecera` añades `display:flex` y `align-items:center` para que los elementos queden centrados verticalmente.
2. En el bloque hijo `titulo` añades `flex-grow:1` para que ocupe todo el espacio restante y `text-align:center` para centrarlo horizontalmente.

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   } 
   #cabecera {
     
    background: #FFFBB9;
    border: 2px solid #0a3fee;
    padding: 10px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
   }
   .logo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
     border: 2px solid #ee930a;
     margin: none;
     
   }
   #titulo{
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:center;
   }
```

```html
<html>
            
<head>
<title>Mi pagina</title>
             
</head>
            
<div id="agrupar">
<header id="cabecera">
<img class="logo" src="LOGO.png">
<h1 id="titulo"> titulo de mi pagina</h1>
</header>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer con `CSS GRID` de este modo:

- Creas 2 columnas con un ancho igual de `1fr`
- Dentro de la etiqueta principal `header` colocas tanto tu imagen como el `h1` dentro de 2 `divs`
- Le asignas un ancho y un alto personalizado a los 2 divs para lograr que no ocupen el 100% del espacio disponible de su etiqueta padre
- Para centrar el texto del título solo aplicas un `text-align: center;`

Código:

```html
    <style>
      header{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        background-color: pink;
      }
      div{
        background-color: red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
      }
      #titulo{
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        Logo
      </div>
      <div id="titulo">
        <h1>Título de la página</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto se produce debido a que las etiquetas h1 tienen por defecto la propiedad `display: block` y esto hace que actúen como bloques y que el texto se baje justo debajo de la imagen.

Sin embargo, puedes hacer que los elementos actúen como elementos `inline` (que se sitúen en la misma línea) pero teniendo las propiedades de los bloques (pueden tener altura, anchura...). Esto se consigue mediante la propiedad `display: inline-block`. De esta manera, el texto se situará a la derecha de la imagen ya que se posicionará en la misma línea que esta.

Por último, podrías utilizar la propiedad `vertical-align: middle` sobre la imagen para que la imagen y el texto se alineen de forma vertical.

Si además quieres centrar el texto horizontalmente en el espacio que queda deberás de ponerle una anchura al header y en el texto hacer uso de la propiedad `text-align: center;` y de la propiedad `calc` para la anchura, la cual te permite hacer cálculos del espacio que queda, en este caso le he restado a la anchura total del header, la anchura de la imagen + los bordes + el padding, tanto de la cabecera como de la imagen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
} 
   
#cabecera {
  background: #FFFBB9;
  border: 2px solid #0a3fee;
  padding: 10px;
}

.logo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #ee930a;
  margin: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#titulo{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 228px);
}
```

```html
<div id="agrupar">
  <header id="cabecera">
    <img class="logo" src="LOGO.png">
    <h1 id="titulo"> titulo de mi pagina</h1>
  </header>
</div>
```